# Start New Notebook with Wolfram Snippet from Linux Console

Tags: scripting, linux

Is there a way to evaluate a snippet of Wolfram code from the Linux console (via `wolframdesktop`, etc) in such a way that the snippet launches a front end (with clean variable state, etc) in a new window?

For example, something similar to

```
wolframdesktop --evaluate-fresh "Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]"
```

should launch a new front end and show the code snippet + the evaluated sin plot for viewing.